# Redirect/Post to localhost instead of external domain

Tags: asp.net, windows, http, redirect, http-post

I have 2 apps, both live, one of them lets say webapp1 uses webapp2 to authenticate user, during that process it posts to a url from webapp2 passing some query parameters as well. recently there are some issues started appearing which can only be replicated in production as the webapp1 only has production instance, so to replicate this issue in local, i need to do something in my dev machine so that when i open webapp1 prod url in my machine, and it redirects to webapp2 prod url to login, it shall actually redirect to same replica of webapp2 in my localhost, IIS 7.5 hosted.

**Details:**
both are web applications, their domain setup like this in prod:

webapp1: https://webapp1.example.com/abc/xyz

webapp2 url: https://www.example.com/webapp2/login.aspx?abc=sometext&State=somestatetext

Now when i open webapp1's production url in my local, and it does post to webapp2's prod url, posting some data to it along with some query parameters, then i want that to rather redirect posting same data and passing same params to local instance of webapp2 running in my local machine,
for example to this:
https://localhost/webapp2/login.aspx?abc=sometext&State=somestatetext

**Is there any way to achieve this without changing anything in webapp1 or 2 in production?**

I feel it doesn't matter much but still webapp2 is aps.net web form app and my local machine is windows 7.

Tried few options but not sure they are right approach:

1. modify host file

modify host file to point example.com to localhost: but as both webapp1 and 2 are in same domain in prod, so i can't access prod url of webapp1 in my local machine, as that tries to open from my local, which i don't want to happen as i need webapp1 prod url to start request to my local.

2. trying this chrome extension:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/switcheroo-redirector/cnmciclhnghalnpfhhleggldniplelbg?hl=en

it looks promising but not sure if that does same what i am expecting/need, means can it mimic exact same post to localhost and pass all params as is?
anyone has any prior experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

Just to share if someone else ends up with same/similar needs.

I ended up using this extension, its pretty useful and helps to redirect request to one domain to another paired domain. Beauty is you need not do anything in hosts file or anywhere else to get it working.

With it, i could map my prod/stage/test to my local dev and have them all saved for future usage and per need i can decide which pair i want browser to use for given testing.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/switcheroo-redirector/cnmciclhnghalnpfhhleggldniplelbg